# Abp version update

Tags: abp, blazorise

hi guys i am trying to update abp version from 5.2.2 to 6.0.1

its single layer web app with blazor server.

I executed abp update then did schema, blazor, npm and yarn update and now when i run app i get this error message from browser console

```
rror: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to set property 'Clicked' on object of type 'Blazorise.BarDropdownItem'. The error was: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.MouseEventArgs]'.
 ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback' to type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.MouseEventArgs]'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.PropertySetter.CallPropertySetter[TTarget,TValue](Action`2 setter, Object target, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.PropertySetter.SetValue(Object target, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.<SetProperties>g__SetProperty|3_0(Object target, PropertySetter writer, String parameterName, Object value)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.<SetProperties>g__SetProperty|3_0(Object target, PropertySetter writer, String parameterName, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.SetProperties(ParameterView& parameters, Object target)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ParameterView.SetParameterProperties(Object target)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at Blazorise.BaseComponent.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SupplyCombinedParameters(ParameterView directAndCascadingParameters)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the `abp bundle` command inside the blazor project. If not, you can review the document -> [here](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Migration-Guides/Index)

Answer (score 0):

after creating new project with abp cli i copied packages versions and it worked. issue was with

```
"Blazorise.Bootstrap5" Version="1.0.4" />
"Blazorise.Icons.FontAwesome" Version="1.0.4" />
```

this is correct version